# How to remove double quotes in csv generated after pyspark conversion

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

When I use pyspark to generate a csv file, the "null" str will be displayed in double quotes:

for example, the input is:

hello  world

(null string)      happy

the csv file generated is:

hello  world

""   happy
you know, when use python to read this file, "" dosen't mean empty string.
So, is there anyway to remove double quotes in csv?
Thx

I try to use .option('nullValue', ''), but it seems not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.option('nullValue', None)` would work

Comment: please accept the answr if it helps you solve uour problem